# linux date command is skipping hours

Tags: linux, date

I'm using the date function to calculate the number of hours passed since a set start date, in my case 19010101. This fails for some dates, the first one being for the last hour of 19160514

```
date -d "19010101 +134710 hours"
```

Sun 14 May 22:00:00 CET 1916

```
date -d "19010101 +134711 hours"
```

Mon 15 May 00:00:00 CEST 1916

23:00 is missing. I also tried

```
date -d "19160515 -1 seconds"
```

Sun 14 May 22:59:59 CET 1916

Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: I'd guess DST changes?..

Comment: The first one returns `Sun May 14 23:00:00 NST 1916` to me.

Comment: The first one returned the result in CET and the second one - in CEST (summer time) timezone. Is this a typo?

Comment: Try running date in UTC timezone, like ```date -u -d "19010101 +134711 hours"``` and post the result.

Comment: Yes that's it. I have to use UTC to avoid local time craziness, i.e. -u solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTC time zone like this:

```
date -u -d "19010101 +134711 hours"
```